Using DateString to textualize a DateObject with the same date and time formatting
I have the following DateObject, which I will store in myDateObject:
myDateObject = DateObject[List[2024, 8, 24, 16, 39, 44.760735`],
  "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.`];
myDateObject

I would like to use DateString to textualize the date object as a string, including the time zone (GMT-4). I come close to the above by using both "DateTimeShort" and "TimeZoneGMTRelative" in the DateString specification:
DateString[myDateObject, {"DateTimeShort", " ", "TimeZoneGMTRelative"}]
(* "Sat 24 Aug 2024 16:39:44 GMT-04:00" *)

I can reformat the time zone using StringReplace and StringDrop:
StringReplace[StringDrop[DateString[myDateObject,
  {"DateTimeShort", " ", "TimeZoneGMTRelative"}], -3], "GMT-04" -> "GMT-4"]
(* "Sat 24 Aug 2024 16:39:44 GMT-4" *)

Is there a better, cleaner way to accomplish this?

The fact that you are doing a replacement of "GMT-04" literally, suggests that you will always be using a -4 time zone offset. Is that really true? Or are you wanting a more general solution that works with any time zone? If it's always -4, then just don't include the timezone in the date string and do a string append of "GMT-4".

If you need a very general solution, you'll need to specify what you want it to look like for positive offsets and fractional offsets.

Let me suggest that we shorten the TimeZoneGMTRelative offset with two rules:

remove the minutes offset if it's :00, and
remove the leading zero from the hours offset.

ClearAll[tzShort]
tzShort[str_?StringQ] := With[
  {s = StringDelete[str, RegularExpression[":00$"]]},
  StringReplace[s, RegularExpression["([+-])0(\\d)"] -> "$1$2"]]

Make some random date strings with time zone offsets for testing.
SeedRandom[246];
dateStrings = Map[DateString[#, {"DateTimeShort", " ", "TimeZoneGMTRelative"}]&,
  Flatten[Map[RandomDate[DateObject[{2024}], 1, TimeZone -> #]&,
    {-4, 5, -10, 11, -9.5, 5.75, -10.5, 12.75}]]];
TableForm[Table[{str, tzShort[str]}, {str, dateStrings}],
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"DateString", "Shortened Time Zone"}}]




DateString
Shortened Time Zone




Tue 30 Apr 2024 21:26:51 GMT-04:00
Tue 30 Apr 2024 21:26:51 GMT-4


Sat 5 Oct 2024 09:04:28 GMT+05:00
Sat 5 Oct 2024 09:04:28 GMT+5


Sat 4 May 2024 09:32:24 GMT-10:00
Sat 4 May 2024 09:32:24 GMT-10


Wed 31 Jul 2024 18:19:15 GMT+11:00
Wed 31 Jul 2024 18:19:15 GMT+11


Fri 5 Jan 2024 00:02:05 GMT-09:30
Fri 5 Jan 2024 00:02:05 GMT-9:30


Tue 20 Feb 2024 09:59:39 GMT+05:45
Tue 20 Feb 2024 09:59:39 GMT+5:45


Thu 2 May 2024 17:15:52 GMT-10:30
Thu 2 May 2024 17:15:52 GMT-10:30


Thu 10 Oct 2024 23:51:53 GMT+12:45
Thu 10 Oct 2024 23:51:53 GMT+12:45



